# Access GitHub wiki via REST API

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to access a GitHub projects wiki-repository via an API as it is with "plain" repositories?

Comment: There is no API for the Wiki. However, you can clone the Wiki as any other repository, since it's stored as a separate repository.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that I do know, wanted to access some resources via an API, but I guess I could put it in a normal repo instead. Thanks.